# Calculating total of ng-repeat Angular JS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a quote system using Angular. I have different items displaying but I'm struggling to generate the total cost. Please see the code below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="part in curOrder.orderParts">
    <td>{{part.partDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{part.partQty}}</td>
    <td>{{part.partPrice * part.partQty | number:2}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <th>Total</th>
    <td>
        {{(part.partPrice * part.partQty)*(curOrder.orderParts.length) | number:2}}&nbsp;{{curOrder.currency}}
        //I know this line doesn't work as it isn't in the ng-repeat.
        //How would I store this expression as a variable so I could use it here?
    </td>
</tr>
```

How would I store {{part.partPrice * part.partQty}} as a variable (maybe 'itemTotal') and then add all them together into something like 'orderTotal' and display that on the page?

I should mention that the price of each part can be altered by the user during this process via an input field. This caused issues with the variable not updating when the user changed the price. The code for this is below:

```
$scope.orderParts = $scope.curOrder.orderParts;
for($part in $scope.orderParts){
$partTotal = parseInt($scope.orderParts[$part].partQuotePrice * $scope.orderParts[$part].partQty);
$scope.curOrder.partTotal += $partTotal;
console.log(
    "\n partQuotePrice: "+$scope.orderParts[$part].partQuotePrice + //Prints 0 as nothing in user input yet
    "\n partQty: "+ $scope.orderParts[$part].partQty + //Prints 100
    "\n Multipled: "+($scope.orderParts[$part].partQuotePrice * $scope.orderParts[$part].partQty)+ //Prints 0 (0*100)
    "\n partQuotePriceTotal:"+$scope.curOrder.partTotal //Prints NaN
);
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is something that you should do in your _controller_. Separate business logic from your views.

Comment: Hi! I tried to multiply these in my JS but the value kept returning NaN, even though console.log was printing out the correct amount. Assigning it to a variable seemed to kill it. Oh! And I forgot to mention, the price of each part can be altered during this process via an input field.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what console.log gives you for each variable? e.g. whether it's a string or not as well?

Comment: repeat <tbody> rather than <tr> may solve ur problem

Comment: @Tom I've added the code in question above, hope this helps clarify!

Comment: Because you concatenate, it will cast all the variables in your console.log to strings. Replace your plus signs with commas and see what that prints (note: in your example, it didn't print 0, it printed "0" - it was a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `$scope.curOrder.partTotal += $partTotal;` - did you ever set `$scope.curOrder.partTotal` to 0?

```
x = undefined
x += 2 // x == NaN
```

If your `$scope.curOrder.partTotal` variable hasn't been initialised, adding a number to `undefined` will give you your `NaN` result.

Comment: Thanks Tom, lifesaver!